# how to use HttpContext.Current in net core 5 (no necromenssing)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net5

before we use net 5 we use net framework.

// Net Framework

`ClsLog.WriteLog(HttpContex.Current, GetType(), "GetManualWeightData", ActionType.Action_Read, model.UID, model, clsResponse, clsResponse.ErrorMsg, model.LogCode);`

//

but now we use net 5 and net 5 cant use current...
how to instaed of "current"?

+

````
 public class ClsLog
    {
        public static void WriteLog(HttpContext current, Type type, string strMethodName, string strActionType, string strUID, object strParam, object strResponse, string strErrorMsg = "", string strLogCode = "")
        {
            string strLocalIP = "";
            string strBrowser = "";
            string strMemID = "";
            string strCustomerID = "";

            if (current != null)
            {
                //strLocalIP = current.Session("LocalIP"] + "";
                //strBrowser = current.Session["BrowserInfo"] + "";
                //strMemID = current.Session["LogID"] + "";
                //strCustomerID = current.Session["CustomerID"] + "";
            }
            try
            {
                Task.Run(() => ClsWriteLog.getInstance().WriteLogServer(new ClsVariableAppLog("AppAPILog", strLocalIP, strBrowser, strMemID, strCustomerID, type.Module.Name, strMethodName, strUID, strActionType, type.FullName, strErrorMsg, strParam, strResponse, strLogCode)));
                //await ClsWriteLog.getInstance().WriteLogServer(new ClsVariableAppLog("AppAPILog", strLocalIP, strBrowser, strMemID, strCustomerID, type.Module.Name, strMethodName, strUID, strActionType, type.FullName, strErrorMsg, strParam, strResponse));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("LogError - " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` type and read its `HttpContext` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components).

Comment: aready inject,, but i cant use `current` 
in ` ClsLog.WriteLog(HttpContext current, GetType(), "GetSyncFunction", ActionType.Action_Read, model.UID, new { model = model }, clsResult, clsResult.ErrorMsg, model.LogCode);` 

how to use `HttpContext.current` ?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` doesn't exist anymore. You need to use `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` instead.